# Find value from one csv in another one (like vlookup) in bash (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, csv, compare, vlookup

I have already tried all options that I found online to solve my issue but without good result.

Basically I have two csv files (pipe separated):

**file1.csv:**

```
123|21|0452|IE|IE|1|MAYOBAN|BRIN|OFFICE|STREET|MAIN STREET|MAYOBAN|

123|21|0453|IE|IE|1|CORKKIN|ROBERT|SURNAME|CORK|APTS|CORKKIN|

123|21|0452|IE|IE|1|CORKCOR|NAME|HARRINGTON|DUBLIN|STREET|CORKCOR|
```

**file2.csv:**

```
MAYOBAN|BANGOR|2400

MAYOBEL|BELLAVARY|2400

CORKKIN|KINSALE|2200

CORKCOR|CORK|2200

DUBLD11|DUBLIN 11|2100
```

I need a linux bash script to find the value of pos.3 from file2 based on the content of pos7 in file1.

Example:

```
file1, line1, pos 7: MAYOBAN
find MAYOBAN in file2, return pos 3 (2400)
```

the output should be something like this:

```
**2400**

**2200**

**2200**

**etc...**
```

Please help
Jacek

Comment: split into arrays and check for duplicates perhaps. Not sure that's the way to do it but that's my first thought.

Answer (score 5):

A little approach, far away to be perfect:

```
DELIMITER="|"

for i in $(cut -f 7 -d "${DELIMITER}" file1.csv ); 
do 
    grep "${i}" file2.csv | cut -f 3 -d "${DELIMITER}"; 
done
```

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values): "each record consists of fields, separated by some other character or string, most commonly a literal comma or tab." and "In common usage, almost any delimiter-separated text data may be referred to as a 'CSV' file."

Answer (score 2):

This will work, but since the input files must be sorted, the output order will be affected:

```
join -t '|' -1 7 -2 1 -o 2.3 <(sort -t '|' -k7,7 file1.csv) <(sort -t '|' -k1,1 file2.csv)
```

The output would look like:

```
2200
2200
2400
```

which is useless. In order to have a useful output, include the key value:

```
join -t '|' -1 7 -2 1 -o 0,2.3 <(sort -t '|' -k7,7 file1.csv) <(sort -t '|' -k1,1 file2.csv)
```

The output then looks like this:

```
CORKCOR|2200
CORKKIN|2200
MAYOBAN|2400
```

**Edit:**

Here's an AWK version:

```
awk -F '|' 'FNR == NR {keys[$7]; next} {if ($1 in keys) print $3}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

This loops through file1.csv and creates array entries for each value of field 7. Simply referring to an array element creates it (with a null value). `FNR` is the record number in the current file and `NR` is the record number across all files. When they're equal, the first file is being processed. The `next` instruction reads the next record, creating a loop. When `FNR == NR` is no longer true, the subsequent file(s) are processed.

So file2.csv is now processed and if it has a field 1 that exists in the array, then its field 3 is printed.

Comment: Great! This worked like a charm. Actually the firs option is fine as I don't need sorting. The output is used for statistical purposes so if the amounts are fine, that's ok. I have tried AWK but without nice results.

Comment: @Yasapl: I added an AWK version to my answer. If you found my answer useful, please mark it accepted and upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller).

Starting from input01.txt

```
123|21|0452|IE|IE|1|MAYOBAN|BRIN|OFFICE|STREET|MAIN STREET|MAYOBAN|
123|21|0453|IE|IE|1|CORKKIN|ROBERT|SURNAME|CORK|APTS|CORKKIN|
123|21|0452|IE|IE|1|CORKCOR|NAME|HARRINGTON|DUBLIN|STREET|CORKCOR|
```

and input02.txt

```
MAYOBAN|BANGOR|2400
MAYOBEL|BELLAVARY|2400
CORKKIN|KINSALE|2200
CORKCOR|CORK|2200
DUBLD11|DUBLIN 11|2100
```

and running

```sh
mlr --csv -N --ifs "|" join  -j 7 -l 7 -r 1 -f input01.txt then cut -f 3 input02.txt
```

you will have

```
2400
2200
2200
```

Some notes:

- `-N` to set input and output without header;
- `--ifs "|"` to set the input fields separator;
- `-l 7 -r 1` to set the join fields of the input files;
- `cut -f 3` to extract the field named `3` from the join output

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d\| -f7 file1.csv|while read line
do 
  grep $line file1.csv|cut -d\| -f3
done
```