# vlookup style query in nested for loop (

Tags: bash, for-loop, nested, vlookup

I've been using the advice in this question:
[Find value from one csv in another one (like vlookup) in bash (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697724/find-value-from-one-csv-in-another-one-like-vlookup-in-bash-linux)

To try and create a script where I go through multiple data files, and add columns in a vlookup style manner, from a couple of other (single) reference files.

datafile example (*.data)

```
info1   7   44567    1   2  marker1
info2   3   143679   2   2  marker2
```

reference file example (ref.txt, file to lookup from)

```
marker1     66%
marker2     34%
```

a second reference file example (ref2.txt, second file to lookup from)

> ```
> info1     exact
> info2     partial
> ```

Output required

```
info1   7   44567    1   2  marker1   66%   exact
info2   3   143679   2   2  marker2   34%   partial
```

attempted loop (showing one reference file only, since I haven't got that bit working yet!)

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `ls /path/*.data`; 
do
for i in $file; 
do 
KEY=$(cut -f 6 $file);
    printf "%s\t" $i;
    grep "${KEY}" /path/ref1.txt | cut -f 2 ; 
done
done
```

I think there are two issues with the script I've written
The output currently is one line per input file, rather than all the lines of the input file appended, and it is the filename of the file rather than a line in the file. The reference bit does seem be working though (from what I can tell with a one line output).
i,e:

```
/path/1.data    66%
```

Can anyone show me what is going wrong, or please suggest a cleverer way to do this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `join` utility for this. In particular, given your example:

```
join -o 1.1,1.1,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2 -1 6 -2 1 test.data ref.txt |
  join -o 1.1,1.1,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,2.2 -j 1 - ref2.txt
```

This produces your proposed output. The `-o <list>` option specifies each field you want printed in the format `<filenumber>.<fieldnumber>`. `-1 <n>` and `-2 <n>` specify which field respectively in each file you want to match, and `-j <n>` is a shortcut you can use when the field number is the same in both files.

Comment: That is really useful, thank you. Much much less complicated than the loop (although at first glance a little daunting!)

Comment: It is a lot of typing... To make it a bit shorter, you could just do `join -1 6 -2 1 test.data ref.txt | join -j 1 - ref2.txt`, but the output would be in a somewhat different order than what you wanted. That could be easily corrected with a post-processing step in `awk` or something though if it was critical.

Comment: can I ask, does this exclude entries where there is no shared key? I might have to post another question but would there be a way to put a blank space or 0 where there was no entry matching the data file in ref file? Thanks.

Comment: Check out the manual page for `join`. There are options to print un-joined lines as well if you need. Putting in "default" entries, though, would have to be either a pre- or post-processing step. Again, `awk` is probably the most useful utility for that sort of thing, unless you prefer `python` or `perl`...