# Like a vlookup but in bash to match filenames in a directory against a ref file and return full description

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am aware there isn't a special bash function to do this and we will have to build this with available tools -- e.g. sed, awk, grep, etc.

We dump files into a directory and while their filename looks random, they can be mapped to their full description. For example:

```
/tmp/abcxyz.csv
/tmp/efgwaz.csv
/tmp/mnostu.csv
```

In filemapping.dat, we have:

```
abcxyz, customer_records_abcxyz
efgwaz, routernodes_logs_efgwaz
mnostu, products_campaign
```

We need to go through each of them in the directory recursively and rename the file with its full description. Final outcome:

```
/tmp/customer_records_abcxyz.csv
/tmp/routernodes_logs_efgwaz.csv
/tmp/products_campaign_mnostu.csv
```

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697724/find-value-from-one-csv-in-another-one-like-vlookup-in-bash-linux) but not sure how to work it out at directory level dealing with only one file as the lookup/referece file. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Sure. for i in $(ls -1); do grep "${$i}" /home/sandy/filemapping.dat | cut -f 2 -d","; done

But that does not rename. Not sure what to do after cut. I'm thinking we have to issue a mv command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
sed 's/,/.csv/;s/$/.csv/' filemapping.dat | xargs -n2 mv
```

Either `cd` to `tmp` beforehand, or modify the `sed` command to include the path name.

The `sed` commands simply replace the comma and the line end with the string ".csv".

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you elaborate what this sed does, please? I need to make some modifications.